# Custom equation solver error

Tags: java, methods, dictionary, compiler-errors, equation

I am having some difficulties getting my custom equation evaluator to work. I pass it a string read from a text file (no spaces except between string words) as equation as well as passing it a map of keywords which link to the values they represent. I have tested that and all of my maps are working properly. Below is my attempt to handle the result regardless of it is an int or a string. These will be the only two allowed entry types. Each side of the equation can have one or two elements to it, separated by either a plus or a minus. The only three operators allowed to evaluate the two sides are <,>,=. Sides are restricted to either having only keywords or only integers, so you can't have something like dexterity + 1 = strength + 2.

The error I am currently getting when I try to compile this class is "no suitable method found for parseint" "method Integer.parseInt(String,int) is not applicable". If I am not mistaken since I am compiling this class directly and not the main class it wouldn't even have the map to make that kind of judgement call. Is this a problem? I am compiling in this way because I have been having issues where recompiling the main class did not recompile secondary class files causing problems.

Any example equation: dexterity>3 or background=Ex Legionary

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Equation {
private String[] sides = new String[2];
private String[] rawEquation = new String[3];
private String[] parts = new String[2];
private String type;
private int[] tempInt = new int[2];
private int[] finalSide = new int[2];
private String[] finalStride = new String[2];

public boolean solve(String equation, Map gladMap) {
    if (equation.indexOf("<") > -1) {
        sides = equation.split("<");
        rawEquation[1] = "<";   
    } else if (equation.indexOf(">") > -1) {
        sides = equation.split(">");
        rawEquation[1] = ">";
    } else if (equation.indexOf("=") > -1) {
        sides = equation.split("=");
        rawEquation[1] = "=";
    }
    rawEquation[0] = sides[0];
    rawEquation[2] = sides[1];
    for (int d = 0; d < 2; d++) {
        if (sides[d].indexOf("+") > -1) {
            parts = rawEquation[0].split("\\+");
            for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
                if (isInteger(parts[a])){
                    tempInt[a] = Integer.parseInt(parts[a]);
                } else {
                    tempInt[a] = Integer.parseInt(gladMap.get(parts[a]));               
                }
            }       
            finalSide[d] = tempInt[0]+tempInt[1];
            type = "Int";   
        } else if (rawEquation[0].indexOf("-") > -1) {
            parts = rawEquation[0].split("\\-");
            for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
                if (isInteger(parts[a])){
                    tempInt[a] = Integer.parseInt(parts[a]);        
                } else {
                    tempInt[a] = Integer.parseInt(gladMap.get(parts[a]));       
                }
            }       
            finalSide[d] = tempInt[0]-tempInt[1];
            type = "Int";   
        } else {
            if (isInteger(sides[0])){
                finalSide[d] = Integer.parseInt(sides[0]);      
            } else {
                if (isInteger(gladMap.get(sides[0]))) {
                    finalSide[d] = Integer.parseInt(gladMap.get(sides[0])); 
                    type = "Int";
                } else {
                finalStride[d] = gladMap.get(sides[0]);
                type = "Str";
                }
            }       


        }
    }
    if (rawEquation[1].equals("<")) {
        if (type.equals("Int")) {
            if (finalSide[0] < finalSide[1]) {
                return true;
            }
        } 
    } else if (rawEquation[1].equals(">")) {
        if (type.equals("Int")) {
            if (finalSide[0] > finalSide[1]) {
                return true;
            }
        } 
    } else {
        if (type.equals("Int")) {
            if (finalSide[0] == finalSide[1]) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (type.equals("Str")) {
            if (finalStride[0].equals(finalStride[1])) {
                return true;
            }
        }   
    }

return false;
} 
public boolean isInteger( String input ) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt( input );
        return true;
    }
    catch( Exception NumberFormatException ) {
        return false;
    }
}   




}
```

I tried to separate the Integer.parseInt() from the gladMap.get(sides[0]) by creating a temporary string variable, but it didn't change anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the map which you are passing is not with the generic types. Hence, get() will always return an object, which is not an appropriate argument for parseInt() method.
Changing the method signature to 
**public boolean solve(String equation, Map< String ,String > gladMap) {**

should solve the errors.

Comment: Excellent. I am still having some trouble grasping the concepts surrounding when and where you should use the generic type versus the specific type. Will mark as answered in a couple mins.

Comment: Generics were added in Java version 5. They are used to maintain the uniformity of the collection as well as compile time safety. They are design to prevent the method to stuff anything in the collection which is passed to it as an argument.
Following blog provides good understanding on when to use generics:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/generics-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be following: your map is untyped so calls like `gladMap.get(sides[0])` return Object. `Integer.parseInt` expects String. You can change it to
 `gladMap.get(sides[0]).toString()`.

It think it should work. If value is actual String then `toString` will return itself, it it is `Integer` it will be converted to string and parsed back.